Raspberry Pi 2 Model B v1.1 missing piece
I recently posted asking for help troubleshooting my Raspberry Pi 2 Model B v1.1, which appears to be "bricked." After some investigation, I believe I may have found the issue, but I need assistance confirming and resolving it.
I've attached images comparing a "working" and "faulty" Raspberry Pi 2. The photos are taken from the back of the board, near the Micro SD reader.

Reference Board: 
Faulty Board (Suspected Missing Component): 
Working Pi for Comparison: 

From what I can tell, there appears to be a missing component on the faulty board, apparently Q7 or Q8. Could someone help identify what this missing component is? Also, is it possible to replace or repair it, and if so, how should I proceed? Any guidance on sourcing the part or specific repair steps would be greatly appreciated!

edit: never mind, as soon as I hit send, I found Q7 or Q8 seems to be missing  - see how all those components are labelled ... could you at least add the label of the component you think is missing, I can't for the life of me find a difference (I think I found Wally though)

You're right, I forgot to add that! Just edited the post.

Do you have any idea what can it be? I'm not good with schematics, so I can't make sense of the board schematics on the official website to try and figure it out on myself

do the schematics on the official website have Q7 and Q8 on them - I'm leaning towards the missing component being Q7, but it still could be Q8 ... the schematics could help, but I don't have the schematics to check against

The only Pi2B schematic I found was for v1.2 - Q7 is shown as DMG2305UX - the chip itself on a v1.1 Pi2B has 23X and B9 on it (the B9 is just a date marker so it's not going to be consistent) - how good are you at soldering surface mount components? I'm 100% confident that the chip is a sub one dollar DMG2305UX

That's it! I inspected it with a magnifying glass and the Q7 component is the same as the one in Q3 (in agreement with the schematics). In the working one, it read out in both Q3 and Q7 components 23XB6 and in the faulty one I managed to read only the Q3 component as 23XB0. But, as you said, the B is just a date marker. I will buy the DMG2305UX diode and try to solder it. Any tips? Also, if you want to post your answer, I will gladly mark it as accepted.

Any tips? for working with surface mount components? Steady hands, good eyesight, patience.

The missing chip is Q7, a DMG2305UX (identical to Q3 nearby) - the markings on it should be 23X and a sideways 2 digit date marker, which is B9 on both Q7 and Q3 on my Pi2B v1.1
I'm no expert, but it looks like Q7 is a vital part of the SD card power circuit, and by vital, I mean, without it, no power to the SD card, which does seem to explain the symptoms you have with that Pi.

Thanks! I will order the piece and solder it. Will post updates if it works or not...
